# If every element of a field is a sum of squares, then how many squares are required?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field such that every element is a sum of squares.  For $\mathbb{F = Q}(\sqrt{-7}),$ four squares might be required. Is there any field such that there are contains elements that aren't the sum of four squares? What is the smallest $n$ that is at most the Pythagorean number of such a field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Lam, Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields,   chapter XI Field Invariants. The level (Stufe) of a field is the number of squares needed to add up to $-1.$  Theorem of Pfister, roughly 1965, the level is either infinity (formally real)  or a power of $2.$ That's page 379.  Let me look for examples...

Here we go, pages 381 and 382, Pfister again: there is a field with any designated level that is a power of $2$